# How to do the tensor products with vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, tensor-products, tensors

Let $n$ be a vector and $p$ a function s.t. $\nabla p = n$. Then can we derive

\begin{align*}
pH = pH (I - n \otimes n), 
\end{align*}
where $H = \nabla \otimes \nabla p$ is the Hessian of $p$, and $I$ the identity?

I think this is equivalent to show 
\begin{align*}
p(\nabla \otimes \nabla p) = p(\nabla \otimes \nabla p) (I - n \otimes n)
\end{align*}
and thus 
\begin{align*}
p(\nabla \otimes n) (n \otimes n) = 0
\end{align*}
Is this true? Why?

Answer (score 0):

The condition $p(\nabla \otimes \nabla p) (n \otimes n) = 0$  means that
the matrix product of the Hessian of p and of the matrix $n\otimes n$ must be zero. This is true if $n=O$ or $p\equiv0$ or if $Hess(p)( n) \perp n$.
For example this can work if $n$ lies in $Im(Hess(p))^{\perp}$.

Now, if you have also that $\nabla p = n$ then a sufficient condition is that $||\nabla p|| = const $  since deriving the squared relation  implies that $Hess(p) (\nabla p) \equiv 0$.

On the other hand there is also a simple  counterexample given by $p=(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2\mapsto \frac {x^2+y^2}{2} \in \mathbb{R}$, 
the Hessian is the identity matrix while the gradient is the identity map of $\mathbb{R}^2$, $\nabla p(x,y) = (x,y)$.

Comment: I wrote $p(\nabla \otimes n) (n \otimes n) = 0$ because of the condition $\nabla p = n$.

Comment: I have updated the answer